# How do I navigate to a new screen without using any button, like a timer?

Tags: android, flutter

I can't navigate to a new screen without having to use a button

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need a little more information. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First of all import dart:async as folows:

```
import 'dart:async';
```

And then In your first page, navigate with a timer to another Screen (In example below, SecondRoute is the new screen) as follows:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 5),
            () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
              );
    });
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks but i don't want it to go back to the first screen. it is a splash page

Comment: In that case, you need to replace 'push' with 'pushReplacement'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  **Future.delayed()**

Example:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
     Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

     Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder(_) => SecondRoute()));

}
```

Comment: The delay won't work, because future is not awaited. Route push callback should be set with `.then()`.

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin its working in my scenario, if you want to use the await keyword inside the initstate you probably need to make the initstate async meaning to error prom step :D